# add an array to a list in flutter

Tags: json, flutter, api, dart

I'm creating a data to an API and these API returns a list that have a nested list and an array. what I wanted to do is combine the array with the nested list and create a new list. my response returns "client" list and "phones" array. I want to create "supplier" list and merge the two data I fetched. the "client" list objects to the "supplier" list as it's object and add "phones" array as an object to "supplier"

the response of the API

```
{
    "client": {
        "name": "Glorymawn",
        "address": "bole",
        "tin_no": 98909876,
        "updated_at": "2022-10-11T16:23:00.000000Z",
        "created_at": "2022-10-11T16:23:00.000000Z",
        "id": 24
    },
    "phones": [
        {
            "id": 59,
            "client_id": 23,
            "phone_number": 90865132314,
            "email": "ism3e@mail.com",
            "model": "Supplier",
            "category": "Manager",
            "created_at": "2022-10-11T16:23:00.160624Z",
            "updated_at": "2022-10-11T16:23:00.160636Z"
        }
    ],
    "message": "Client created successfully"
}
```

what I want to create is

```
{
"supplier": {
    "id": 24,
    "name": "Glorymawn",
    "address": "bole",
    "tin_no": "98909876",
    "created_at": "2022-10-11T16:23:00.000000Z",
    "updated_at": "2022-10-11T16:23:00.000000Z",
    "phones": [
        {
            "id": 59,
            "client_id": 23,
            "phone_number": 90865132314,
            "email": "ism3e@mail.com",
            "model": "Supplier",
            "category": "Manager",
            "created_at": "2022-10-11T16:23:00.160624Z",
            "updated_at": "2022-10-11T16:23:00.160636Z"
        }
    ]
}
```

}

my create call

```
    Future createSupplier(
    String name, String address, String tin_no, List<Phones> phones) async {
  Uri url = Uri.parse("${BASE_URL}supplier");
  SupplierController supplierController = Get.put(SupplierController());

  final response = await http
      .post(url,
          headers: <String, String>{
            'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
            'Authorization': 'Bearer $TOKEN',
          },
          body: jsonEncode(<String, dynamic>{
            'name': name,
            'address': address,
            'tin_no': int.parse(tin_no),
            'phones': phones.toList()
          }))
      .then((value) {
    if (value.statusCode == 200) {
      supplierController.setsupplierPress(true);
      print(json.decode(value.body)['client']);
      supplierController.createSupplier(
          Suppliers.fromJson(json.decode(value.body)['client']));
      Get.back();
      supplierController.setsupplierPress(false);
      print('<<<<<<<<<<' + value.body);
      print(json.decode(value.body)['client']);
      print("success");
    } else if (value.statusCode == 500) {
      Get.snackbar("Data Exists", "The data you provided already exists.");
    } else {
      Get.snackbar("Failed", "Failed to create client, try again later");
    }
  });
}
```

how can I make this happen?

Answer (score -2):

Just head to the [json2dart](https://javiercbk.github.io/json_to_dart/) and paste your json there then it will give you the classes you need

After that its simply decoding your response from server the class will do the job you need